# Primefaces 5 con JSF enviar datos a otra vista desde una tabla

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Buen día, estoy comenzado a trabajar con **`JSF`** y **`primefaces`** y tengo una duda

tengo una tabla con el siguiente código:

```html
  <h:form id="tabla">
    <p:dataTable var="sel" value="#{adminbean.seleccioness}" rows="5"
                         paginator="true"
                         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{sel.pk_equipo}" />
        </p:column>
 
        <p:column headerText="Nombre">
            <h:outputText value="#{sel.nombre}" />
        </p:column>
 
        <p:column headerText="Seudonimo">
            <h:outputText value="#{sel.seudonimo}" />
        </p:column>
 
        <p:column headerText="Continente">
            <h:outputText value="#{sel.continente}" />
        </p:column>
        
    <p:column headerText="Puntaje">
            <h:outputText value="#{sel.puntaje}" />
        </p:column>   
        
        <p:column headerText="Acciones">
             <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-disk" title="Exportar"></p:commandButton>
             <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" title="Consultar" action="consultasel">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{sel}" target="#{consultaSelecciones.selselected}" />
             </p:commandButton>
             <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Eliminar"></p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
         
        <f:facet name="paginatorTopLeft">
            <p:commandButton type="button" icon="fa fa-sync" />
        </f:facet>
 
        <f:facet name="paginatorBottomRight">
            <p:commandButton type="button" icon="fa fa-cloud-upload" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>
```

y tengo un boton consultar que deseo que me abra otra vista y mostrar los datos ahi pero cuando presiono click me sale el siguiente error:

```
 `Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Objetivo inalcanzable, 
  identificador 'consultaSelecciones' resuelto a nulo`
```

este es mi `bean` consultaSelecciones

```
  package com.app.controller;

  import java.io.Serializable;

  import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
  import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
  import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
  import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
  import com.app.entity.selecciones;

  @ManagedBean
  @ViewScoped
  public class ConsultaSelecciones{

public selecciones selselected;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    selselected = new selecciones();
}   

public selecciones getSelselected() {
    return selselected;
}

public void setSelselected(selecciones selselected) {
    this.selselected = selselected;
}
```

En mi aplicación no tengo configurado el `faces-config.xml`, no se si sea por eso, o quisiera saber que otras formas hay de enviar dichos datos a otro vista, cabe resaltar que los otros `bean` me funcionan normal, solo este que esta dentro del **`setPropertyActionListener`**

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿a qué te refieres con enviarlo a otra vista?, en JSF configuras que vista usa que Controller, si tienes 2 vistas puedes configurarles que usen el mismo Controller

Comment: Revisa el alcance de los bean, en tu caso de viewScoped puedes revisar (https://www.arquitecturajava.com/jsf-1-2-vs-jsf-2-0-ambitos-y-escalabilidad/)

Comment: Según veo en tu `bean` utilizas el scope `@ViewScoped`. Este scope no te conserva los datos si haces el cambio de una vista a otra. Tendrías que utilizar otro scope como `@SesionScoped` o pasarlos a traves de `<f:param` y capturarlos en el mismo `bean`